# Allow exactly two instances of Electron Main Process, but not more?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, instance

I'd like to allow Electron to start a second `main` process when a user runs the executable a second time, but exit the process if it's a third instance.

I have the following code for handling a second instance of the application differently than the first, but I'm not sure how I can detect if it's a third instance with Electron 3.

---

#### Electron Main Process: `Index.js`

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

if (gotTheLock) {  
  app.on('second-instance', (argv, workingDirectory) => {
    //  Do some things
  })
} else {
  //  If instance does not have lock -
  //  require this file in the first instance without lock
  require('./host');

  //  Otherwise exit the new instance
  //  HOW CAN THIS BE ACHIEVED????
}
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of `electron`, BUT I think using a file might do the trick. Have a file at some location which keeps track of the list of `pid`s of the instance opened. When a new instance is opened, check the file. If the length of the `pid` list is greater than 2, close the instance. ( You will need to make sure though that the file is in sync with the instances all the time )

Comment: @AnandUndavia you're right, but I'm hoping there's a more proper way to do this with Electron that I'm overlooking, since there is already a mechanism for managing multiple instances.